# Android change height width of view according to requirements at runtime

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a textview at runtime and I am rotating it at 120 degree, using `mytextview.setRotation(120);`.

The problem to do is it cutting my text (not able to see text outside view)

My layout is

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do? The rotation angle is dynamic and changes depending upon user. How to overcome this problem?

Actually I am able to rotate a view, but my textview not display entire string. i.e if string is Hello then after rotation it only display Hel and after that words are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

one of this two options can help you:

```
 android:adjustviewbounds="true"
```

programmaticly at runtime: after the rotation you can set the widht and height with:

```
 view. getlayoutparams().widht = ...
 view. getlayoutparams().height = ...
```

Comment: using view. getlayoutparams().widht = ... view. getlayoutparams().height = .. it will fix size but i need it according to dynamic different screen and different string length

Comment: then write a method where you set your layout params dynamic in depending to your source params (screen, string). in my mind there is no official android solution. you can take a look on this project https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout